# NetBeans replace word with another word from the text

Tags: php, regex, codeigniter, netbeans

I'm new to PHP coding and I made a mistake in the code.
I have like 400 occurrences of a method that I want to change but I don't know how.

I've heard about regular expressions, but I can't apply to this case because I dont know so much of RegExp.

I have this in my code, for example

```
<?php echo $lang['extension_not_allowed'] ?>
```

I want to change all the results with $lang for $this->lang(''), for example

```
<?php echo $this->lang('extension_not_allowed') ?>
```

There's any way to do it using Ctrl+Shift+H (Global Replace) in NetBeans?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes look at the menu `Edit -> Replace in Projects` it allows a global find/replace on the whole project. You dont need  regex, its just a simple find replace over all files in the project of you can for example limit it to `*.php`

Comment: Yes, but the text inside the $lang['Text'] changes, and I need to take the text inside the variable to replace with the $this->lang('text'), how I can do it?

Comment: Find: \$lang\['(.*?)\] -- Replace: $this->lang('$1');

Comment: Try `(<\?php.*?)\$lang\[([^]]*)]` regex with `$1$this->$lang($2)` replacement. See [example](https://regex101.com/r/wO3zO7/2). Or remove the `(<\?php.*?)` and use `\$lang\[([^]]*)]` to replace with `$this->$lang($1)`.

Comment: Thanks @stribizhev , it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following regex with replacement:

```
 (<\?php.*?)\$lang\[([^]]*)]
```

And the replacement:

```
$1\$this->\$lang($2)
```

Or remove the `(<\?php.*?)` part if the `$lang` may appear on lines without `<?php`:

```
 \$lang\[([^]]*)]
```

and replace with `"\$this->\$lang($1)"`.

**See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/wO3zO7/2)**

A couple of notes:

- `(<\?php.*?)` - matches and captures the text `<?php` and 0 or more characters other than a newline, as few as possible (with `.*?`)
- `\$lang\[` - matches `$lang[` literally (note that special regex characters must be escaped)
- `([^]]*)` - matches and captures 0 or more characters other than a `]` (we are using a character class `[...]`)
- `]` - a literal `]`.

Comment: I'm tryin to use the query  \$lang\[([^]]*)] and replacing by $this->lang->line($1)  but i got the error "Illegal group reference". Why ?

Comment: Have a look at this [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/Sm23Wg). You need to escape the `$` in the replacement pattern that is a literal `$`. It seems you can also just escape the literal `$` like `\$`.